# twig, cannot loop hash called by variable name

Tags: twig

Why does this not work:

```
{% set relations = [{'cat':'friends','foo':'bar1'},{'cat':'enemies','foo':bar2},....] %}
{% set friends = [{'firstName':'John', 'lastName':'Goodman'},....] %}
{% set enemies = [{'firstName':'Ron', 'lastName':'Badguy'},....] %}

{% for relCat in relations %}
    {% set list = relCat.cat %}
    {% for person in list %}
        {{ person.firstName }}
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

I admit that I 'm pretty new to twig, so I really searched and searched, but cannot find a solution for my problem (that I thought to be trivial) ....

I hope someone can help - I lost all my hair over this, thanks, Rudolph

Comment: You need to state in what way it does not work (error message, or undesired behavior) and what you expected it to do.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OK, it should, output the names, but it doesn't output anything at all......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of variables is important
So first: enemies and friends:

```
{% set friends = [{'firstName':'John', 'lastName':'Goodman'}] %}
{% set enemies = [{'firstName':'Ron', 'lastName':'Badguy'}] %}
```

Then set relations: again `friends` not `'friends`', first is variable, second a string:

```
{% set relations = [{'cat':friends,'foo':'bar1'},{'cat':enemies,'foo':bar2}] %}

{% for relCat in relations %}
    {% set list = relCat.cat %}
    {% for person in list %}
        {{ person.firstName }}
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

And this should work

See [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/a6vk95)

Comment: Oops, I'm afraid I forgot a line. The code in my original question works. What does NOT work is when you do it through a variable. I edited the question.

Comment: cause you set list variable to string 'friends'? Check what will happen when you make it `{% set list = friends %}`

Comment: OK, of course, that works. I realize I oversimplified the problem. I updated the question. I understand that the real problem is that the variable is a string...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `_context` variable if you *really* need to keep strings:

```
{% set relations = [{'cat':'friends','foo':'bar1'},{'cat':'enemies','foo':bar2}] %}
{% set friends = [{'firstName':'John', 'lastName':'Goodman'}] %}
{% set enemies = [{'firstName':'Ron', 'lastName':'Badguy'}] %}

{% for relCat in relations %}
    {% set list = _context[relCat.cat] %} {# <--- here #}
    {% for person in list %}
        {{ person.firstName }}
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

See [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/a6vk95/2)